# PHP, Apache, MySQL old version installation

Tags: apache

I need to install PHP 5.1.6, MySQL 5.0.95 and Apache/2.2.3 on my computer. Where could I get these versions? I tried to install Apache 2.3.3 on Wamp. Problem is it install but it doesn't want to run with PHP 5.1.6. When I try to select PHP 5.1.6 version I get the following message:

```
This version doesn't seem to be compatible with your actual Apache version.
```

What can I do to make it work? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to install them separately ?

- Apache 2.2.22 (can't find the 2.2.3): http://mirror.mkhelif.fr/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/
- PHP 5.1.6: http://museum.php.net/php5/
- MySQL 5.0.96 (can't find the 95): http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is problem combining that PHP version with that Apache version on Windows OS. I've solve the problem by using Apache 2.0.x